# Javascript local storage preferences

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, web, local-storage

I have the following script:
I want my app to access and remember for the second launch one of this pages:
This is how I tried but it's not working.

```
<script>
if (localStorage.getItem("0") === null) {
//do nothing 
}
else if(localStorage.getItem("1")===null{
}
else if(localStorage.getItem("2")===null{
}
else if(localStorage.getItem("3")===null{
}
else if(localStorage.getItem("0") !==null){
window.location = "cosmote.html"
}
else if(localStorage.getItem("1") !==null){
window.location = "germanos.html"
}
else if(localStorage.getItem("2") !==null){
window.location = "zapp.html"
}
else if(localStorage.getItem("3") !==null){
window.location = "sunlight.html"
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is not working? What is a happening? Have you debugged to see where it is failing?

Comment: I think you have a to many "(" in the last ifs or is it just a typo

Comment: Yes I saw but is not from there:(

Comment: What i want is the app to open directly with one  of this page when its launched for the second time. But it's still open with the main page>

Comment: When I put only one if and one else it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you not be better, sotring the last page value in one local storage area?

Then doing one call e.g `localStorage.getItem("lastPage");`

Then doing a switch or if else again, this will save mutliple accesses to local storage.

This will make it more efficent and readable, or if this isnt the case at least use an object and a value for each page.

Comment: I'm beginner, I don't know how to do that, could you please give me an example? Thanks

Comment: e.g. localStorage.setItem("lastPage","PAGE NAME") then var lastPage = localStorage.getItem("lastPage") to get the last page... Then use your if statements to say if(lastPage == "index") do what ever

Answer (score 0):

You also have a few extra parentheses in there.  Not sure if that's your problem or not.

Check out http://www.jstorage.info/ for a small, simple Javascript library for interacting with local storage.

Comment: Thank you but the problem is not from there, was an edit error.